# NetBeans look&feel same as resulting one

Tags: java, netbeans, look-and-feel

I am trying to find a java look&feel that can be used in NetBeans (I'm currently usign version 14) to have a "what you see is what you get" result

As I said here: [netbeans design missing bold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71747401/netbeans-design-missing-bold), I was using the Metal l&f, both in NetBeans (by launching it with the "--laf javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel" parameter) and in the code

But lately it doesn't work as it used to: in NetBeans the varoius graphical objects (labels etc...) have a "normal" font, but when i run the project, they have a bold font, which makes them larger and ruins their positioning. Thus I can't create a good graphical interface anymore, because I have lost the "what you see is what you get" effect

I have also tried different l&f, for example Nimbus. With it, I can solve my problem: NetBeans correctly shows the graphical objects as expected. But imho Nimbus has a big lack: non-editable obects (for example text fields) are showed identical as editable ones! (the Metal l&f instead makes a good work at this)

I'm searching for a l&f that can correctly be displayed by NetBeans, and that can differentiate between editable and non-editable objects. Can you point me out any?

Answer (score 0):

Try com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel.

You need not to put startup options in NetBeans, check look and feels Tools / Options / Apperance menu.

Another workaround would be making all non-editable widgets to be disabled - setEnabled(false).